# What happened to Shula after Dragon Ball and what happened to the golden blade?

Tags: dragon-ball

I was wondering what happened to Shula after the events of Dragon Ball. I know a lot of characters in Dragon Ball are mentioned in one episode only and then completely forgotten afterwards, such as in *The Darkness* when Goku was searching for the ultra divine water, or the thunder crown from when Goku was training with Kame and Mr. Popo.

But during the Buu saga, we hear that the ruler of the underworld was Dabura and not Shula. **Does that mean Shula was overthrown? Has something else transpired?**

Comment: The ultra divine water comes up later in DBZ. But Shula hasn't been heard from again, according the very-fallible wiki:
Shula has never escaped ever since, but it is likely that he is still alive.

Comment: They should bring back that golden blade, because that thing looked sick. Maybe it's stronger than the Z sword?

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that not everything that happened in the Dragon Ball/Z anime is canon. From the [Dragon Ball Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_(franchise)#Dragon_Ball_canon):

> Episodes often include filler, which is material that was not in the manga. This is due largely to the manga and the anime being produced in parallel; it was often necessary for the anime to add filler material to keep from getting ahead of the manga. These extended sequences often add detail to the back story. The original Japanese version is considered by some to be a more authoritative source than other dubs due to occasional translation errors. Some of the filler contradicts later additions made by Toriyama itself, like Dragon Ball Minus.

As you can see from the [Dragon Ball Wikia page on Shula](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Shula), he never appeared in the manga and thus was not a true canon character. Thus, if there is something with a higher "canon priority," such as Dabura being the ruler of the Underworld, that would take precedence over a filler character such as Shula. While this answer may leave something to be desired, there aren't any better explanations, unfortunately.